# How to include sqlite database file in R package. so that I can share/publish it along with database file?

Tags: r, database, sqlite, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I have a SQLite database like run.sqlite in my **local computer**. I am making an **R package** which contains some code and that runs on this SQLite database. How can I make a R package which contains this database too. So, that I can share/publish my R package in CRAN/github.

Comment: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html but CRAN has pkg size restrictions/guidelines so you may need to make this a separate data pkg for the sqlite file depending on how big it is.

Comment: not sure if this is a good way but maybe you could include your data as a simple .csv file in your package and add a function in your package that, given a path to some dir, makes the sqlite db there.

Answer (score 3):

I put an sqlite file in my R package using the method from the [Raw Data section](https://r-pkgs.org/data.html#data-extdata) in the R package documentation.

Put your sqlite file in the folder `inst\extdata\` in the package root, then in your package get the path to it using.

```
system.file("extdata", "sqlite.db", package = "package-name")
```

For example:

```
db_file = system.file("extdata", "sqlite.db", package = "package-name")
con = DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = db_file)
```

Comment: Apparently this method will fail in a staged installation, unless the call to `system.file` is inside a function. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63530442/how-to-use-files-in-inst-extdata-r-package-check-prevent-to-use-system-file-i) and [here](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2019/02/14/staged-install/).