# How to correctly use data in extdata/data folder

Tags: r, package, r-package, cran

I am working on an R package that I would like to submit to CRAN and have had issues with the size of the data, therefore I moved it into the extdata/data folder in order to use in my examples but I am getting fatal errors that are not allowing my package to pass the checks.

[The GitHub repo](https://github.com/sistia01/DWLS)

I've tried a few different solutions (i.e. `system.file()` & `load(system.file()))` which have not worked. The files are RData files.

```
#' load(system.file("extdata", "trueLabels.RData", package = "DWLS"))
&
#' system.file("extdata", "trueLabels.RData", package = "DWLS")
```

How can I use the data in the extdata/data folder in my @examples of the functions without encountering build errors?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that your files will not be available for loading with `system.file` until the package is installed. So at build time the examples will not have them, only will be there when the package is available, `devtools::load_all()` does not do the trick.

> `load(system.file('extdata','<filename>.RData', package = 'DWLS'))` is the way to go, in any case.

You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67664911/4534783) and [here](https://pubs.wsb.wisc.edu/academics/analytics-using-r-2019/read-rdata-files.html)

I've seen in your [repo](https://github.com/sistia01/DWLS/blob/main/R/DEAnalysisSeurat.R#L18:L23) that you try to get the data with `download.file()` but failed at check job. You can try to use `tmpfile()` as destination.